# Python Matplotlib plt.show() does not return the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, display

I remote login a server using `ssh -X ***@remote.arizona.edu` (This remote server is a Linux system) and tried to make some plots using Python, I had the following errors:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Then I fixed this error by the adding the commands before I import any `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

Now it runs well. But the problem is that there is no figure displayed even if I had the command `plt.show()`. My old computer used Ubuntu 16.04 before, there is no such problem. Now I switched to MacBook Air, then I had this issue. It must be some Mac setting issues. Any thoughts to fix this issue?

Comment: try execute on terminal: export DISPLAY 0.0 and after execute your code

Comment: configure X11Forwarding  on your remote desktop

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you. I tried the command, but it says `-bash: export: `0.0': not a valid identifier`. I tried the exprot DISPLAY, but nothing happens.

Comment: I think it is not supported on a server.

Comment: @DaveQ Thanks. So you mean I need to contact the computer manager to report this issue, ask him to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) on your Macbook. Then make sure the DISPLAY variable in your remote shell is set to your local X server. Now the remote `matplotlib` should show the figure on your Macbook.

Comment: OK, it works. I need to comment out the `matplotlib.use('Agg')` command. Thank you very much.